# Spark/Yarn UI views all use dns name not IP:port name, any way to change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

So, through the spark resource manager, all of the links to different applications, logs, etc all use DNS name

`ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.company.com:20888/proxy/application_11111` for example

I must manually copy this and cange it to `xx.xx.xx.xx:20888/proxy/application_11111` to view this webpage.  Is it possible to get the original link working or change all of the links to `xx.xx.xx.xx:20888...` format?

Comment: Are you able to find any solution? I'm facing the same problem with `20888` & `19888`